# Ruby on Windows7 - could not find gem

Tags: ruby, windows-7, rubygems, buildr

I'm setting up a ruby Apache Buildr on a fresh Windows 7 machine.
I've installed Ruby, the DevKit and installed buildr via

```
    gem install buildr
```

wich all ran perfect.
Until I tried to execute buildr, then I get an error.

```
    buildr compile

    C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find buildr (>= 0) amongst [atoulme-Antwrap-0.7.1, builder-2.1.2, buildr-1.4.5-x86-mswin32, buildr-as3-0.2.12, diff-lcs-1.1.2,highline-1.5.1, hoe-2.3.3, json_pure-1.4.3, minitar-0.5.3, minitest-1.6.0, net-sftp-2.0.4, net-ssh-2.0.23, rake-0.8.7, rdoc-2.5.8, rjb-1.3.2-x86-mswin32-60, rspec-2.1.0, rspec-core-2.1.0,rspec-expectations-2.1.0, rspec-mocks-2.1.0, rubyforge-2.0.3, rubygems-update-1.8.4, rubyzip-0.9.4, xml-simple-1.0.12] (Gem::LoadError)
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1182:in `gem'
    from C:/Ruby192/bin/buildr:18:in `<main>'
```

When I list all the gems with

```
   gem list buildr
```

Everything seems to match up, and this error makes no sense at all.
[image]

Any ideas?
Help would be great, I'm getting desperate now. :)

Comment: I've got exactly the same problem; running with admin privileges doesn't change anything.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I'm having the same problems with Ruby187

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same problem. I have Windows 7 x64 so installed again with `gem install buildr --platform mswin64` and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in the past.

My problem was the kind of installation.
I installed ruby as admin (target was c:\program files). Everything worked fine - until I installed a gem as normal user (not admin).

What happened on windows side? I have no authorization for c:\program files, the gem was installed in another directory (No, there was no error, Windows just decided to use another directory. This bug/feature is called 'Virtual Store').

In the end Ruby had problems to find the files.

My solution:
Install ruby as normal user outside c:\program files.

Maybe it is enough, when you install your gems as admin (but attention: if you have once files in your Virtual store, they are read always first.).

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

I installed Ruby in the installation directory C:\Ruby192 as me (not as admin, but as a user with admin rights)
So I don't think this is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Installed Ruby 1.8.7 instead and it works now.